# Am I glad to see you!

Tags: expressions, word-order, greetings

> Am I glad to see you!

It's my first time I've met this expression, but I don't completely understand why "Am" is placed before "I" and thought it would have derived from its interrogative form because it's the rule to place "Am" before a subject when to make a question, but interestingly, there's an answer on Quora that it has nothing to do with the interrogative but just an exclamatory expression.

I think such a structure can be explainable to think in this way that it's permitted to write such that when a speaker wants to emphasize a current situation "Am" but am not sure it'd be a reasonable thinking.

To add, I would like you to bring such examples as many as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, it is an interrogative construction. Note that the exclamation mark emphasises that it is a 'rhetorical' question, not expecting an answer (here, of course, the questioner already knows the answer!).

To make sense of this idiom think of it as a *contraction* of the question-and-answer form, 'Am I glad? - Yes I am!'

In speech, there is strong emphasis usually on the first part, with no rising (question) tone at the end of the exclamation. (Of course, in English, inflection changes the meaning: the emphasis might be on 'I','see' or 'you' depending on context. This is another subject...)

Other examples:
 - After the rock concert, Tom exclaims,'Wow, were they **loud**!'
 - Harry, looking at Pete's freshly bruised face, 'Are you going to feel that **tomorrow**!'

Also, you will hear negatives, used with irony:
 - 'Wow, weren't **you** angry!' (ie yes you were angry); 
 - 'Aren't **you** the clever one!' (ie yes you are the clever one); 
 - 'Don't you look **great**!' (ie Mmmm beautiful!).